# How can I count data by group in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have data of program usage in excel file, the data has date and time. I want to summarize this information that in each day each hour, how many user use this application. How to do that using excel formular?

sample data:

```
Jun 01, 09:03AM
Jun 01, 10:00AM
Jun 01, 10:50AM
Jun 01, 11:00AM
Jun 01, 11:26AM
Jun 02, 01:00PM
Jun 02, 03:00PM
Jun 02, 04:04PM
Jun 02, 08:00PM
Jun 02, 11:00AM
Jun 02, 12:00PM
Jun 01, 10:50AM
Jun 01, 11:00AM
Jun 02, 11:00AM
Jun 02, 12:00PM
Jun 02, 01:00PM
Jun 03, 08:00PM
Jun 03, 09:00PM
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a pivot table.

Create a new column call *'Day'* next to your data.  Put a formula in the column to extract the day.

```
=DAY(A2)
```

Create a pivot table based on the two columns of data.

- Row fields = Column 1 dates
- Column fields - Column 2 day
- Data items - Count of Column 1 dates

Group the Row fields by hours.

If you want the full day (i.e. Jun 1) then instead of creating a day column, create a copy of your data in a second column.  Use the two columns in the pivot table and group the new column by day.

---

To do the same purely by formulas in Excel 2007.

Extend the data by adding two columns.
Call the first column *'Day'*.  Put a formula in the column to extract the day.

```
=DAY(A2)
```

Call the second column *'Hour'*.  Put a formula in the column to extract the hour.

```
=HOUR(A2)
```

Create a table layout with columns headed 1 to 31 for days and rows headed 0 to 23 for hours.

Insert the following formula (adjust cell references as required)

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$19,F$1,$C$1:$C$19,$E3)
```

Copy the formula to fill the table.

The `COUNTIFS` function is new to Excel 2007.  It works in the same way as the `COUNTIF` function, but allows multiple ranges and criteria.

Comment: Image links out of date